# Ошибка подключения библиотеки material dialogs

Tags: java, android

Где можно скачать или может у кого есть файл библиотеки 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.3.1', чтобы подставить в libs локально, пытался установить

```
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.4.2@aar') {
   transitive = true
}
```

Но выдает что надо поднять версию до 23, но при поднятии выходят все новые и новые ошибки(, так как приложение мало используется, не планируется его поддерживать и потому легче было бы просто подставить либу.

Comment: Может, в таком случае стоит "поиграться" с версиями библиотеки в build.gradle?

Comment: @ahgpoug чем это поможет?

Comment: Предыдущие версии библиотеки могут требовать версии, ниже 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел кое как файл 
так же надо добавить в gradle

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

и

```
dependencies {
compile(name:'material-dialogs-0.6.3.1', ext:'aar')
```

а в app/libs подставить файл [файл](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2s7h5f8272mjob7/material-dialogs-0.6.3.1.aar?dl=0%22%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%22)